# Не конвертируется Py файл в exe

Tags: qt, pyqt5

При попытке конвертировать py файл в exe с помощью Pyinstaller вылезает ошибка:

```
> C:\Users\Денис\Desktop\ПИТОН\python\Приложение\Unit4a\Финальная
> склейка\exe file>pyinstaller ListeningTask2.py 282 INFO: PyInstaller:
> 4.0 283 INFO: Python: 3.8.3 284 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0 287 INFO: wrote
> C:\Users\Денис\Desktop\ПИТОН\python\Приложение\Unit4a\Финальная
> склейка\exe file\ListeningTask2.spec 293 INFO: UPX is not available.
> 301 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
> ['C:\\Users\\Денис\\Desktop\\ПИТОН\\python\\Приложение\\Unit4a\\Финальная
> '  'склейка\\exe file', 
> 'C:\\Users\\Денис\\Desktop\\ПИТОН\\python\\Приложение\\Unit4a\\Финальная
> '  'склейка\\exe file'] 350 INFO: checking Analysis 350 INFO: Building
> Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 351 INFO:
> Initializing module dependency graph... 362 INFO: Caching module graph
> hooks... 436 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... 10663 INFO:
> Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
> 10668 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib'
> 22145 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 22770 INFO: running
> Analysis Analysis-00.toc 22778 INFO: Adding
> Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final
> executable   required by
> c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
> 23099 INFO: Analyzing
> C:\Users\Денис\Desktop\ПИТОН\python\Приложение\Unit4a\Финальная
> склейка\exe file\ListeningTask2.py 23265 INFO: Processing module
> hooks... 23267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> 23276 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> 23603 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> 23863 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> 24164 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found! 24166 INFO: Loading
> module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> 24447 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations
> C:/users/äåíèñ/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/translations\qtbase_*.qm.
> These translations were not packaged. 24449 INFO: Loading module hook
> 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from
> 'c:\\users\\денис\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
> line 194, in _run_module_as_main
>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\Денис\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py",
> line 7, in <module>   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
> line 114, in run
>     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
> line 65, in run_build
>     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 720, in main
>     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 667, in build
>     exec(code, spec_namespace)   File "C:\Users\Денис\Desktop\ПИТОН\python\Приложение\Unit4a\Финальная
> склейка\exe file\ListeningTask2.spec", line 6, in <module>
>     a = Analysis(['ListeningTask2.py'],   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 242, in __init__
>     self.__postinit__()   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
> line 160, in __postinit__
>     self.assemble()   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 419, in assemble
>     self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py",
> line 365, in process_post_graph_hooks
>     module_hook.post_graph()   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 440, in post_graph
>     self._load_hook_module()   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 406, in _load_hook_module
>     self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py",
> line 588, in importlib_load_source
>     return mod_loader.load_module()   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in
> load_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787,
> in load_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in
> _load_module_shim   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219,
> in _call_with_frames_removed   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py",
> line 13, in <module>
>     hiddenimports, binaries, datas = add_qt5_dependencies(__file__)   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py",
> line 538, in add_qt5_dependencies
>     more_binaries = qt_plugins_binaries(plugin, namespace=namespace)   File
> "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py",
> line 146, in qt_plugins_binaries
>     pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)   File "c:\users\денис\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py",
> line 128, in qt_plugins_dir
>     raise Exception(""" Exception:
>             Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
>             Paths checked: C:/users/äåíèñ/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins
> 
>
```

Из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: `Paths checked: C:/users/äåíèñ/...` русские символы в пути к файлам... Не всякие программы их любят. Создайте нового пользователя с логином из латиницы либо используйте `venv` в папке с путем, содержащим только латиницу.

Comment: Поменял имя пользователя на английское, всё заработало, спасибо